# DXGI desktop capturing

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-9, dxgi

I'm doing desktop capturing in a loop with `DXGI`. In that I call this function in loop.

```
dxgiSurface1->Map(&map, DXGI_MAP_READ)
```

But sometimes `map.pBits` is `null`. I cannot figure out at what time. It's like random times. If I increase the `Sleep()` time in the loop it's not become `null`. Please tell me the reason...

Comment: Where does `dxgiSurface1` come from?  By "desktop capturing" do you mean you're using [DDA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: When I use Sleep(1000) before IDXGIOutputDuplication::AcquireNextFrame function it works fine. But if the time value of Sleep() is small (eg : Sleep(10) ) ,then map.pBits doesn't get  correct values.

Comment: Do you check the HRESULT returned from Map? The GPU may already be accessing the surface when you make the call, preventing you from accessing the memory concurrently.